# String variable doesn't print correctly

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, chat

So I am writing a multi-client chat and I would like to display the name of every client in front of the message. when I print the variable "client_name" in the main function (the line "clients_dictionary[current_socket.getpeername()]" returns the value it's supposed to, doesn't return None) by itself it shows up fine, but when I try to join it to the body of the message ("data = client_name + ": " + data") it prints as ": *whatever was in the variable data*". What am I doing wrong?

```
import socket
import select
HOST = ""
PORT = ""
open_client_sockets = []
messages_to_send = []
clients_dictionary = {}


def handle(server_socket):
    client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
    open_client_sockets.append(client_socket)
    client_name = client_socket.recv(1024)
    clients_dictionary[client_address] = client_name


def main():
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server_socket.listen(10)
    while True:
        r, w, x = select.select([server_socket] + open_client_sockets, open_client_sockets, [])
        for current_socket in r:
            if current_socket == server_socket:
                handle(server_socket)
            else:
                try:
                    data = current_socket.recv(1024)
                except socket.error:
                    data = ""
                if data == "":
                    open_client_sockets.remove(current_socket)
                else:
                    client_name = clients_dictionary[current_socket.getpeername()]
                    data = ": " + data
                    data = client_name + data
                    print data
                    messages_to_send.append((current_socket, data))
                    w.remove(current_socket)
                    for client_socket in w:
                        if client_socket != current_socket:
                            client_socket.send(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: If you print out `client_name` right before `print data` in the `else` block, it still shows up fine?

Comment: yes it does, I can't figure it out. I placed it above the "data = ": " + data" line, it printed the name i entered on the client.

Comment: That is weird...If it were me, I would put a `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` line right before your `print data` call, and see what you can figure out interactively.

Comment: it just printed:
> ~path~\server.py(39)main()
-> print data
(Pdb)

Comment: The `(Pdb)` part should be an interactive prompt though, so you can use it just like the Python interpreter. So from there you can do things like print out the values of your variables, try concatenating them  interactively, check object types; whatever you want to do. Your program will be paused at that point in the code until you enter `c` for continue

Comment: I printed the "data" variable. After the name I entered from the client, it has a "\r". Is it related?

Comment: Possibly, but I am not really familiar with the `socket` stuff so it is hard for me to say. The `"\r"` represents a carriage return.

Comment: Hello!. Probably its too late, but consider using string formatting - it will erase `'\r'` in string representation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

anyway you better be use python string formatting:

```
chat_msg = '{}: {}'.format(client_name, data)
```